# issue when converting html string to pdf using evo pdf library

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, evopdf

I got a problem when converting html string to pdf, to be simple, I found the Kendo js/css file I referenced in my html string looks like not working at all.

Detail:
I am working on a project that converting my views(ASP MVC 4.5
) to Pdf using Evo Pdf, in my view, I have used Kendo UI controls, so I reference the Kendo css js file like below in my view file

```
@Scripts.Render("~/Libs/KendoUI/js/kendo.all.min.js")
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Libs/KendoUI/js/kendo.all.min.js")"></script>
```

When I open the view in browser, all controls works fine, but when I render the view into string, and pass it to Evo SavePdfFromHtmlStringToStream  function, the pdf is generated but all the Kendo controls are missing on the pdf.

Ps, I know maybe I can use the absolute URL to convert URL to Pdf, but I am using view with model(model are posted to controller), so I don’t really want to do that.

Comment: Did you set a base URL as parameter for SavePdfFromHtmlStringToStream  to resolve the relative URL of the JS file to an absolute URL which can be accessed by converter?

Comment: Yes, mate, I got the solution 2 weeks ago from their supporting team by emailing. thanks~!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I found the solution 2 weeks ago from Evo team, I just need set a base url in the parameters, that's all, now works fine! thanks for all!

Comment: Would you be so kind to expand your answer with a code example, how you solved it?

Comment: @BKM honestly, cant remember the solution any more,its been so long while now , but documentation should help you out .